# Algorithm for partitioning large area of coordinate space into smaller ones on-the-fly when certain conditions are met

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, geospatial, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I am working on a project of partitioning area of coordinate space. As I need your help, I've explained in detail. So it does not seem difficult to understand the problem.

Dividing large areas into small sections that fit the criteria is the key. The criteria are described as below. I think there are three approaches to solve specific problems that I'm trying to solve. If you think there is a better approach to this problem, please recommend.

First, when the intersection of lanes is called node, the large area of the coordinate space consists of numerous edges(= lanes) that join the nodes, and each edge has a specific value. I want to divide a large area into as many smaller sections as I want, where the edges within the segmented zone must be adjacent to each other and the sum of the values of the edges in divided zone is similar to other small divided zone.( = balancing)

```
<Data information>   

[edge_id] : edge1, edge2, edge3 ,, etc
[edge_value] : 10, 5, 20,, etc
[edge_node1_id]: n1_1, n1_2, n1_3,, etc
[edge_node1_latitude] : 37.29188, 37.28342, 37.29563,, etc
[edge_node1_longitude] : 127.09838, 127.10327, 127.10221,, etc
[edge_node2_id]: n2_1, n2_2, n2_3,, etc 
[edge_node2_latitude] : 37.29191, 37.28301, 37.29632,, etc 
[edge_node2_longitude] : 127.09840, 127.10333, 127.10314,, etc
```

Second, it is similar to the above method, but if the above method is difficult, center point of the edge can be used instead of the edge. In other words, the values of edge can be replaced by the the value of center point of edge and rest of the process is similar to above. I would like to divide the zone by points that are close to each other instead of the first condition mentioned above(the adjacency between the edges). And I want to make sure that the sum of the values of each point within the divided zone is similar to each other zones. (= balancing)

```
<Data information>

[center_node_id]: c_1, c_2, c_3 ,,etc
[center_node_value]: 10, 5, 20 ,,etc
[center_node_latitude]: 37.25116, 37.25143, 37.25184 ,,etc
[center_node_longitude]: 127.11383, 127.10511, 127.10003 ,,etc
```

Third approach is the so-called multi-cut approach in graph or network theory. It would be much easier to understand if you look at the picture. Connecting to the center point of adjacent regions by line, we can create a graph. And by selecting the appropriate link, we can make cluster. we can divide the graph as many as we want. The constraint is the sum of the values of nodes that are connected in the same cluster is similar to sum of values of other connected nodes in other cluster. (=balancing)

```
<Data information>

[node_id]: n_1, n_2, n_3 ,, etc
[node_value]: 10, 5, 20,, etc
[node_adjacency_data] : Please refer to the attached picture.
[node_latitude]: 37.25201, 37.25211, 37.25219,, etc
[node_longitude]: 127.10195, 127.11321, 127.11377,, etc
```

I would appreciate it if you could give me some recommendations on what kind of algorithms can be used to solve any of the three parts that I mentioned above and the reason for recommendations. And the final goal of the project is to solve the problem by implementing code, so I would really appreciate it if you could give the source code or links of the algorithm that you recommend. 
(I can use java or python) .Can you please help me with this? if you don't understand this problem or have questions please tell me.

[image]

[[image: enter image about adjacency data description here]]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AngelKoh Hi, I tried to solve this problem by setting mathematical modeling with optimization. However I found that this problem is kind of NP Hard, so it took huge amount of time to solve by optimization. So I think it needs heuristic algorithms but I don't know which algorithms can be applied to this problem. Could you help me on this?

Comment: All of such problems are NP hard, even k-means, if you want to find the true optimum. So you will have to use a greedy approximation. A good optimizer is likely the way to go.